# no option to install Ubuntu alongside windows10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Ubuntu was previously installed along side windows 10.Until the motherboard was replaced. After that I could not access to Ubuntu any more, booting directly to windows 10. Now after deleting the Ubuntu partition and re-setting windows 10, using usb flash drive installer in -installation type I can read:
 "this computer currently has no detected operating system, what would you like to do?" Erase disk and install Ubuntu. While I need it alongside windows 10.

In other options /dev/sda3 ntfs 1 tera unknown.

After going through multiple forum and tried many things nothing has helped so far.

Comment: is the installer booting in the same mode as windows?  UEFI vs Legacy?

Comment: 1. Install needs to be done on a Linux filesystem. 2. The option alongside only appears when it is possible to install alongside: you need unallocated space ie anempty partition.

Comment: Just make an extra partition of about 20 gb and 2 gb for swap if you have less ram(<4 gb) then.       via installation select "something else" and then format that partition as ext4 and that 2 gb as swap . Select 20 gb partition as main filesystem and proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem here!
In the Bios settings, I unticked the legacy (rom) option making the usb flash drive bootable in UEFI mode making windows visible again...That simple.